# Convergence-probability

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

> Let $X_{1}, X_{2}, \ldots,X_{n}$ be independent, $U(0, 1)$-distributed random variables, and set $Z_{n} = \max({X_{1},X_{2}, \ldots,X_{n}})$
> and $V_{n} = \min({X_{1},X_{2}, \ldots,X_{n}})$. Determine the limit distribution of $nV_{n}/Z_{n}$ as $n$ goes to infinity.

I solved it in this way :
$$U = V_{n}/Z_{n}$$
$$P(nU< u ) = P( U < u/n ) = F_u (u/n)$$

but for finding $F_u$, I wonder to know if it is possible to find distribution of $\min X_{k}$ and $\max X_{k}$ seprately and then divided to each other, and if not, how can I find $F_u(u)$?

Comment: Please learn how to write [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is to calculate the **joint** distribution of $(V_n, Z_n)$.  For $a<b$, we have
$$
\mathbb{P}(V_n > a, Z_n \leq b) = \mathbb{P}(X_1, \dots, X_n \in (a,b]) = (b-a)^n,
$$
so the joint CDF is given by
$$
F_{(V_n,Z_n)}(x,y) = \mathbb{P}(V_n \leq x, Z_n \leq y) = \mathbb{P}(Z_n \leq y) - \mathbb{P}(V_n > x, Z_n \leq y) = y^n - (y-x)^n.
$$
We can then obtain the joint density by differentiating:
$$
f(x,y) = \partial_y \partial_x F(x,y) = n(n-1)(y-x)^{n-2}.
$$

Now we want to calculate, for fixed $t>0$, the probability $\mathbb{P}(n V_n / Z_n \leq t)$.  This amounts to just integrating the joint density $f_{(V_n, Z_n)}$ over the region $x \leq \frac{t}{n} y$:
$$
\mathbb{P}(n V_n / Z_n \leq t) = \int_0^1 \int_0^{\frac{t}{n} y} n(n-1) (y-x)^{n-2} \,dx\,dy = 1 - \frac{(1-t/n)^n}{1-t/n}
$$
(I omit the details of calculating this integral, but it's nothing fancy).

Finally, taking $n \to \infty$ we find
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{P}(n V_n / Z_n \leq t) = 1-e^{-t},
$$
which we recognize as the CDF of **the exponential distribution with parameter $1$**.

Comment: Thank you so much , it was very useful , I just have a question about how to change this equation \mathbb{P}(V_n \leq x, Z_n \leq y) to \mathbb{P}(Z_n \leq y) - \mathbb{P}(V_n > x, Z_n \leq y) = y^n - (y-x)^n, I undestand the first part ( \mathbb{P}(Z_n \leq y)) but not the second one (\mathbb{P}(V_n > x, Z_n \leq y))@Adam

Comment: @sarast It is just the statement that $P(A \cap B) + P(A^c \cap B) = P(B)$